# Assign value to dynamically in IEnumerable type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to assign value to  dynamically in `IEnumerable` type variable.

```
IEnumerable<Infor> qARepotInfor = new List<Infor>();     
var query= from q in db.tblqu
           select q;
var Ques = query.ToList();
```

I want to assign Ques vales to `qARepotInfor` variable.

How to do it?

Comment: What is qARepotInfor? Is it a property on your Info class or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the type `Infor` is defined. I think what you're looking for is:

```
var qAReportInfor =
    (from q in db.tblqu
     select new Infor(q.Field1, q.Field2)).ToList();
```

That's assuming that you can create a new `Infor` instance from the data returned by the query.